# Почему событие onclick вызывает перезагрузку страницы?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться.
Есть пара кнопок, которые добавляют в текстовое поле теги типа [code][/code] и [blockquote][/blockquote]. После нажатия на кнопку теги появляются и тут же происходит перезагрузка страницы - теги исчезают(

Пример кода:

```
 <form action = "" method = "post">
  <input type = "submit" onclick="document.getElementById('text').value='[code][/code]'" value = "Добавить код" />
  <textarea cols="60"  rows="7" name="text" id="text"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В событии onclick нужно вернуть false. Вот так:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('text').value='[code][/code]'; return false;"
```

Comment: Спасибо:) А как сделать, чтобы теги не затирали уже введенный текст и еще чтобы курсор оказался между тегами - [code]|[/code]